# SVG animate along path

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have an `svg path` that I need to animate a shape along here: https://jsfiddle.net/m8hvhtg3/

My issue is that I need to have browser support in `IE9` and the main libraries I have tried like Snap or `D3` don't seem to provide support for `IE9` in terms of animating something along an `SVG path`. Just wondering if this is possible at all and even better if there are any libraries out there that I could use? So for i've had no luck in finding any and can't think of another way around doing this.

Suggestions other than using animation along `SVG path` are welcomed!

Thanks

**EDIT**

Could this be done by converting the SVG shape to Canvas maybe?

Comment: why are you supporting IE9? even Microsoft don't support IE9 anymore

Comment: you might find `stroke-dashoffset` useful https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: Client demands IE9 support

Comment: I don't think that will help as already the link doesn't work in ie9..

Comment: hope you're charging them extra for IE9 support? it's a disgrace for anyone to still be using that nowadays